# appcelerator view disappears on animation

Tags: animation, view, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm making a slide out menu in Titanium Appcelerator for an iPad app. There is a window that holds a slide menu view and another view consisting on two views grouped in a view that acts a container. The thing is that when I try to animate when I click on the menu button the container that holds the two views disappears and it appears again when I close the menu and the animation completes. This is the code of the function that animates the menuview and after it completes animates the contenedortotal view that contains two views.

```
function clickMenu(direction){
       if(menuView._toggle === false && (direction==null || direction=='right')){
            //alert('paso por clickMenu'+menuView._toggle+' '+direction);
          menuView.animate({
            left: 0,
            duration: 200,
            curve:Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_IN_OUT
        },function(){
            //alert('paso por clickMenu'+menuView._toggle+' '+direction);
            contenedorTotal.animate({
            left: 200,
            duration: 200,
            curve:Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_IN_OUT
        });
        menuView._toggle=true;
     });
    }else if(direction==null || direction=='left'){
        menuView.animate({
            left: -200,
            duration: 200,
            curve:Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_IN_OUT
        },function(){
            contenedorTotal.animate({
            left: 0,
            duration: 200,
            curve:Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_IN_OUT
             });
         menuView._toggle=false;
     }); 
    };   
}
```

Comment: If you want a Slide Menu, you can use this great module : https://github.com/viezel/NappDrawer